# FFMPEG Command Execution using libffmpeg.so file

Tags: android, ffmpeg

How to Execute FFmpeg command using libffmpeg.so file? Vec.io site using generating .so file but i don't know how to execute ffmpeg command using libffmpeg.so file 
Please give hint or steps how to execute in android
Thanks in advance

Comment: `.so` files are libraries means they can't be executed directly; must be wrapped into an executable. in ffmpeg configure, use `--enable-program` to build executable, which you can execute! try `./configure --help` for all available options

Comment: You should learn NDK or search for open source projects providing the functionality you need.

Comment: Unknown option "--enable-program" -when i m executing vecio step used